# how to schedule import of data from excel to sql server?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, scheduled-tasks

I am trying  to import data from excel file that is already stored in database.
I am using visual studio 2013 but here i tried to search for the SSIS feature which could have helped me but i didn't find SSIS feature for which i found a lot of tutorials so is there any other way how i can import data from excel table to sql server and then schedule the same task every 5min or for a certain time?
If anyone can suggest me sql command for this task it would be helpful.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "from excel file that is already stored in database" Do you mean the physical excel file is stored in the database, or the data from the excel file is already in the database? Have you tried the import/export wizard from SSMS?

Comment: Have you followed these steps successfully: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/ Is the issue that you want to schedule your package? What happens if the data in the excel file already exists in the database?

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = 'name the link',
    @srvproduct = 'Excel', 
    @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    @datasrc = 'location of your file',
    @provstr = 'Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;'
```

this script create a link to your excel sheet and you can create a job in your sql to gran the info from the source and import it to your local table whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but should be able to create a "Linked Server" object to that excel file.  Write a script that does what you want it to do, then create a SQL Server agent job running that script.

I personally would do an SSIS package and run that SSIS package on the interval you want.